# Dato extraño en base de datos mysql - wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hace un tiempo me encontré en un proyecto datos guardados de esta forma:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:4:"info";s:8:"info";s:6:"info";s:6:"info";s:6:"info";s:2:"info";s:3:"info";s:78:"info";}}
```

sin embargo como no necesitaba hacer nada con esto no le preste mucha atención,resulta que en esta ocasión he vuelto a encontrarme este caso y me pregunto por que? es decir me parece un json pero no logro entender, por favor alguien explíqueme o orienteme por donde buscar mas información al respecto.

Comment: Suena a algo de Wordpress... ¿había alguna instalación de Wordpress o un sitio web corriendo baja Wordpress  o algo así? ¿Cómo se llama la tabla donde están esos datos?

Comment: Efectivamente es wordpress, es la tabla de metas de los post

Comment: Si tienes algún sitio funcionando en WP conviene no tocar esos datos. Ahora bien, si no tienes WP puedes eliminar todas las tablas `wp_`  pero en cualquier caso guarda una copia de seguridad de la base de datos antes de hacerlo, nunca se sabe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente ese dato está serializado.. puedes usar unserialize de php sobre el string completo. te dejo el link de la documentación oficial:

- serialize: http://php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php
- unserialize: http://php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php

ej:

```php
$array = [
    'name'     => 'username',
    'age'      => 100,
    'nickname' => null,
];

$serialized = serialize($array);
echo $serialized;
// output: a:3:{s:4:"name";s:8:"username";s:3:"age";i:100;s:8:"nickname";N;}

$unserialized = unserialize($serialized);
var_dump($unserialized);
// array(3) { ["name"]=> string(8) "username" ["age"]=> int(100) ["nickname"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: Ya entiendo, entonces si quiero acceder a un valor para cambiarlo solo tendría que acceder por la clave del array asociativo, eso era amigo jajaja muchas gracias!

Comment: así es, además se almacena el largo de la key y del valor asi que ojo: al modificar el valor debes modifcar el largo y el tipo si corresponde .. haz pruebas con tildes y caracteres especiales para que veas el comportamiento: se agrega un valor al largo (largo+1).. si se modifica de manera incorrecta el unserialize no funciona

Comment: para reemplazar cosas en arrays serializados de wordpress podes usar [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/)

Answer (score 0):

En el código muchas veces añadimos cosas que luego no le damos uso, o simplemente pasamos a otra cosa y nos olvidamos.
A mi me recuerda a una costumbre que tengo yo de ordenar el codigo y supongo que es algo parecido, en mi caso por ejemplo despliego un mapa con servidores por el mundo y los servidores los agrupo por zonas, pues bien antes de obtener y cargar los datos de los servidores suelo crear un array con una estructura similar a aquella en la que después introduzco los datos.

```
$zonas= [ 
        "Zona1" =>["X" =>6.50,"Y" =>84.50,"servers"=>[],"cant"=>0],
        "Zona2" =>["X" =>49.60,"Y" =>22.00,"servers"=>[],"cant"=>0],
        "Zona3" =>["X" =>7.50,"Y" =>71.00,"servers"=>[],"cant"=>0]
];
```

Y después simplemente introduzco los datos de cada servidor a su respectiva zona.

> A mi al menos es a lo que me suena esa estructura, deduzco que en algun momento del funcionamiento de la pagina se utilizara para almacenar mas datos y mantenerlos de forma ordenada